Ubuntu Studio 24.04 - Pipewire questions
I have been using JACK to manage audio in ray session (previously kxstudio tools) for around a decade. I have my system dual booted with a shiny new 24.04.1 Ubuntu Studio on a shiny new SSD. But for the life of me I cannot get my head around some of the stuff Pipewire does.

Applications that play sound simply disappear after they play sound and then auto connect to outputs 0-1 when they reappar next time they play sound.

When using Jack Mixer, if I run the mixer output of, let's say my mic, into the mixer input for my remote guest, that just doesn't work. No level appears on the mixer for the input on the channel that goes to my remote guest. Same for any output from Jack Mixer actually, cannot send it to the input of another channel on Jack Mixer.

There doesn't seem to be a control panel for Pipewire. I'd like to set default behaviors. For example, my monitors are running from ch 4-5 on my interface and no matter what I do, when I am just using the computer to do daily tasks (not running the big route  for my podcast) it sends any and all audio to ch 0-1.


Everything seems to work great, low latency, no xruns, new kernel seems to offer some performance improvements. I have quite a long time till 22.04 reaches end of life, so there's no huge hurry here, but any help would be greatly appreciated.
TIA
